# User Defined Dynamic Workflow for web based application ASP.net C#

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, design-patterns, architecture

I was wondering that the Microsoft developed the Workflow Foundation which is used in the application flow but used during development. Its nice! But is their any standard practice to give workflow of an ERP system to user in web environment and user can define the different workflow.

I am going to design the system which provides user for changing workflow.

1. Roles are Defined in the database.
2. Role based workflow system which user can handle run time.
3. Defining process,request,Actor,Actions,status.
4. User can write Rules on its own.

i am Expecting **suggestion**, **New ideas**, **Existing system** which can be see online.

I am using asp.net 3.5, c# and MSSql Server 2008.

Comment: Were you able to achieve this?